# Проблемы с работой watch

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm, gulp-watch

watch не видит 'mincss', хотя остальные таски отлично видит (видно через console.log).

В чем проблема не могу понять.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const connect = require('gulp-connect-multi')();
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: 'site'
    });
    browserSync.watch('site/**/*.*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

//html

gulp.task('template', () => {
    gulp.src('./dev/*.html')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(htmlmin({
            collapseWhitespace: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/'))
});


// style

gulp.task('style', () => {
    gulp.src('./dev/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/'))
});

//css-min 

gulp.task('mincss', () => {
    gulp.src('./dev/css/*.css')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});



//script



gulp.task('script', () => {
    gulp.src('./dev/js/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/'))
});


// image



gulp.task('image', () => {
    gulp.src('./dev/img/*')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/img/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    gulp.src('./dev/img/svg/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/img/svg'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});


//watch


gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('.dev/css/*.css', ['mincss']);
    gulp.watch('./dev/*.html', ['template']);
    gulp.watch('./dev/scss/*.scss', ['style']);
    gulp.watch('./dev/js/*.js', ['script']);
    gulp.watch('./dev/img/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}', {cwd: './dev/img'}, ['image']);
});

console.log(gulp.watch('.dev/css/*.css', ['mincss']));
console.log(gulp.watch('./dev/*.html', ['template']));

gulp.task('default', ['mincss', 'template', 'style', 'script', 'image']);
gulp.task('dev', ['default', 'serve', 'watch'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно надо поменять:

```
gulp.watch('.dev/css/*.css', ['mincss']);
```

на

```
gulp.watch('./dev/css/*.css', ['mincss']);
```